# grails - bug in scaffolded view generation for Floats (Grails 2.0 RC1 - RC3)?

Tags: grails, scaffolding, grails-2.0

If one has a Float field in a domain class, the Grails view generation uses a

```
<g:field type="number" />
```

and one gets a

```
<input type="number" />
```

type of html field, which purely allows integers .... unless I'm just unable to get it to work differently.

Can one override the scaffolded generation to use something else for Floats, e.g. a simple text field, so that a floating point value can be entered?

Thanks

P.S.  I can't find any documentation on the g:field tag, apparently new in this release.  Can you refer me to any reference you've seen or include the documentation in this post?  (if available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voting for [the bug in the Grails bug-tracker](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8143) might help get it fixed.  There's also a workaround

Comment: Super, I'll have to search those better.  Voting for the bug sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

This could be fixed by using the widget constraint which allows you to define a custom html element to be generated by scaffold.

Exp:

description widget: 'textarea'

http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Constraints/widget.html

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.